# Acumatica - Change Field Attributes of Dropdown

Tags: customization, acumatica

I have a Usr field that was custom in a project at one point. Since it has been compiled into a .dll so I do not have the original files to change this Usr field. When I click on the field and go to customize attributes it is not found because it is a Usr Field and not in the Data Access. Is there a way I can change the items that are in the dropdown list of this Usr Field if I can't find it in the Data Access? I have tried going to override on screen level with a PXStringList change and this did not work.

If I need more details please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one of the following ways:

1. Create `CacheExtension` for the `DAC` of that Field and override the property with `Attributes`.
2. Create `CacheAttached` event in the `Graph` and overwrite the `Attributes`.
3. Use `PXStringListAttribute.SetList<DAC.field>(cache, row, allowedValues, allowedLabels)` method to change the list of values and labels.

Below is example how to change the Attributes of the field using `CacheAttached` event:

```
[PXDBString(3, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[PXStringList(new string[] {"comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4", "comp5", "comp6", "comp7"}, new string[] {"comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4", "comp5", "comp6", "comp7"})] 
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Company")]
protected virtual void ARInvoice_UsrDivision_CacheAttached(PXCache cache){}
```

Comment: public class ARRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister>
  {
      #region UsrDivision
    [PXOverride]
    [PXDBString(3, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXStringList(new string[] {"comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4", "comp5", "comp6", "comp7"}, new string[] {"comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4", "comp5", "comp6", "comp7"})]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Company")]
    public string UsrDivision { get; set; }

    public class usrDivision : IBqlField{}

    #endregion
  }

Comment: I used the code above with no luck, this is a the CacheExtension way

Comment: @Dane your `UsrDivision` field is defined in the **Extension of the ARRegister** and not in the `ARRegister` try to write `CacheAttached` event or change the list with `PXStringListAttribute.SetList`

Comment: @Dane I think you don't need to add `PXOverride` attribute as it is used to override Actions and not attributes or methods.

Comment: I tried the SetList and I keep getting usrDivision is not found int the ARRegister DAC, I know that but ARRegisterExt is not valid either. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @Dane add the code you are trying to use and add the exact name of the DAC Extension where the usrDivision is declared

Comment: protected virtual void ARInvoice_UsrDivision_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {
PXStringListAttribute.SetList<ARRegister.usrDivision>(
    cache, null, new string[] {"comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4", "comp5", "comp6", "comp7"}, new string[] {"comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4", "comp5", "comp6", "comp7"});
    }

Comment: @Dane I have added an example to the answer

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! Now I know that the Cache goes beneath the changes.